# What does %*c means?

Tags: c++, c

I'm studying C/C++ through the book "*C++ the complete reference*", and I'm stuck at a tic toe game. The program has this statement:

```
scanf("%d %*c %d",&x,&y)
```

What is this `%*c?` The book didn't explain it at all.

Comment: Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)!

Comment: The first and second [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=scanf) for `scanf` both answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps some of those `%` are actually `&` ?

Comment: @Daniel: You might want to re-read the chapter on `scanf()`, in particular the **Supressing Input** section: "*You can tell scanf() to read a field but not assign it to any variable by **preceding that
field's format code with an `*`**.*"

Comment: That chapter was on page 200, the tic tac toe game, was on page 108, fuk logic on this books man...haha but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

`*` is an optional **suppression flag**. It tells `scanf()` to read the input text per the indicated specification (in this case, `%c` for a single character), but do not output the value to a caller-provided variable. So, for example, given the input `"5 & 10"`, `%*c` will read and ignore the `&` character, and the two `%d` specifications will output the `5` and `10` values to the `x` and `y` variables, respectively.